# Azure Diagnostic Logs Size Limitation

Tags: node.js, azure, logging, azure-diagnostics

I am running a Node.js app in Azure. The existing Azure web app logging feature limits the application logs to a maximum size, which means I cannot retrieve logs from over a day ago (for example). I am able to modify some config/log settings from the Resource Explorer.

For instance I can edit the following properties:

```
... 
"httpLogs": {
  "fileSystem": {
    "retentionInMb": 35,
    "retentionInDays": null,
    "enabled": true
  },
  "azureBlobStorage": {
    "sasUrl": null,
    "retentionInDays": null,
    "enabled": false
  }
},
...
```

I do not see any 'retentionInDays' or 'retentionInMb' properties for 'applicationLogs'.

```
"applicationLogs": {
  "fileSystem": {
    "level": "Off"
  },
```

Is it possible to increase the storage time or size limit for application logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that Azure limits Web Server and Application Logging to 12hrs, but this is not applied to Node.js logs. There is a default limit for the number of total log files, which is set to 10.

The following configurations can be changed to accommodate for whatever you want, though it was cautioned to not do this in production due to a performance hit:

`loggingEnabled: true
maxLogFileSizeInKB: 128
maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB: 1024
maxLogFiles: 20`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to redirect STDOUT and STDERR to a file and then you won't depend on microsoft to capture and save them for you:

`var access = fs.createWriteStream('./api.access.log');
process.stdout.write = process.stderr.write = access.write.bind(access);`

Comment: `createWriteStream` locks the file in the filesystem, so we cannot access the file while the application is running. We have to stop the app first in order to release the file, which isn't an acceptable option.